# Linear probing code

Tags: c++

I need to be able to perform the following using linear probing. I believe the above code should be able to do the job but its not compiling correctly. Any advise will be greatly appreciated.

In and Array from `x[0]` to `x[7]`, for `n = 8`, insert 3, 11, 15, 23 and 31.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

class Hashmap {

private:
int* table;
int used;
int limit;
int* hist;

void grow() {
    cout << "resizing" << endl;
    limit = limit*2;
    return;

}

public:
Hashmap(int initialSize) : table(new int[initialSize]), limit(initialSize),     used(0), hist(new int[0]) {
        int i;
    for (i = 1; i <= initialSize; i *= 2){
        ;
    }

    table =  new int[i];
    used = 0;
    limit = i / 2;
    hist = new int[60];
}



~Hashmap() {
    delete [] table;
}


int hash(int v) {
return v & (sizeof(table) - 1);
}

void add(int v) {
used++;
if (used > limit)
    grow();
int i = hash(v);
int count = 0;
while (table[i] != 0) {
    i = (i+1) % sizeof(table);
    count++;
    if (count >= 60)
        count = 59;
    hist[count]++;
}
table[i] = v;

}

bool contains(int v) {
    int i = hash(v);
    while (table[i] != 0) {
        if (table[i] == v)
            return true;
        else
            i = (i + 1) % sizeof(table);
    }

}

void output() {
table[0] = 0;
cout << table[0];
for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++)
cout << "," << table[i] << endl;

}
};


int main() {

Hashmap m(8);
int n;
for (int i = 3; i < 32; i = i + n){
    if (i == 11) {
    n = 4;
    m.add(i);
    }
    else
    n = 8;
    m.add(i);
}

m.output();



}
```

Comment: What's the error and on what line?

Comment: your code can pass compilation, but it will run into dead loop.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly you have a compilation **warning** with a clear message:

> main.cpp:71:3: warning: control may reach end of non-void function [-Wreturn-type]

`bool contains(int v)` should return a boolean but you don't have any at the end of the function.

Then you have another problem if you try compiling with those flags: -Wall -Wextra -Werror

> main.cpp:22:59: error: field 'limit' will be initialized after field
>   'used' [-Werror,-Wreorder]

Again the message is pretty clear, your order of initialization for the HashMap class is wrong, you need to initialize `used` before `limit` because your variables were declared in that order.

> private:
>
> ```
> int  *table;
> int  used;
> int  limit;
> int  *hist;
> ```

Therefore:

> Hashmap(int initialSize)
>
> ```
> : table(new int[initialSize])
> , used(0)
> , limit(initialSize)
> , hist(new int[0])
> ```

The compiler is your friend, learn to understand its rant it will help you understand your code and defects.

PS:
It's a bad practice to have naked pointers in your code, it's very much C-style.

Try using C++ features, such as vector instead.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, if you wanted to get the number of elements (the size) of table using `sizeof(table)`, you won't get it. 
 
You defined table as a `int *` so `sizeof` will give you the number of bytes that make up the pointer.

If you insist on using a C array that you want to allocate at runtime, you need to keep the size of it as a separate variable.

(By the way, if you were to initialize your table like a fixed size array `int table[5]` you would be able to get the length like this: `sizeof(table)/sizeof(int)`. But you don't want this here or you won't be able to have a dynamic hash table. )

Second, even if you were getting the table size with your current code, if the array does not contain at least one 0 entry and v is not present, you will never exit the following loop because you keep iterating in circle over it (using modulo table size)

```
bool contains(int v) {
    int i = hash(v);
    while (table[i] != 0) {
        if (table[i] == v)
            return true;
        else
            i = (i + 1) % sizeof(table);
    }

}
```

At the very least, you should exit after a full round, returning false.